# link button inside html table cell asp.net

Tags: asp.net

Hi i am dynamically creating link buttons as shown below. the problem is how to add the link button in the place of "`linktopage`". currently the link button is added below the table.

```
for(i=0;i<100;i++)
{
LinkButton lnk = new LinkButton();
lnk.ID = "lnk" + i;
lnk.Text = "open profile";
lnk.Click += new System.EventHandler(lnk_click);
this.Page.Form.Controls.Add(lnk);

htmlstring += "<tr style='height:30px;'>" +
              "<td>" + firstname + "</td>" +
              "<td>" + surname + "</td>" +
              "<td>" + email + "</td>" +
              "<td>" + mobile + "</td>" +
              **"<td>" + linktopage + "</td>" +**
              "</tr>";
                  }
```

Comment: where does the `linktopage` comes from?

Comment: i just added it as dummy placeholder. actually i want the linkbutton to be added there. for example it should be rendered as first name, surnmae,email,mobile,htmllink

Comment: so, your `linktopage` is an action page, like, executing a page, or executing a command? Do you want this to be synchronously or asynchronously?

Comment: actually i want to call a c# method which does some operation and redirects to another page.

Comment: then, that's the normal behavior of a `POST`, if you use the `Command` instead `Click` event you can even pass variables to your method

Answer (score 2):

from your comments

in **.aspx.cs**

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            Populate();
    }

    private void Populate()
    {
        List<MyTableData> list = new List<MyTableData>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            list.Add(
                new MyTableData()
                {
                    FirstName = "Firstname " + i.ToString(),
                    LastName = "Lastname " + i.ToString(),
                    Email = "Email " + i.ToString(),
                    Mobile = "Mobile " + i.ToString(),
                    CmdArgument = i.ToString()
                });
        }

        gv.DataSource = list;
        gv.DataBind();
    }

    protected void lnkBtn_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        string btnNumber = e.CommandArgument.ToString();

        // more code...

        lit.Text = "Button pressed <b>" + btnNumber + "</b>";
    }
}

public class MyTableData
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    public string CmdArgument { get; set; }
}
```

in **.aspx**

```
<div>
    <asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="5">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="First name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="Last name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Mobile" HeaderText="Mobile" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBtn" runat="server" OnCommand="lnkBtn_Command" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("CmdArgument") %>'
                        Text='<%# Eval("CmdArgument", "Button {0}") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
<hr />
<asp:Literal ID="lit" runat="server" />
```

the **result** is

[image]

> [Source Code **available**](http://ge.tt/8MNx2V4)

Comment: @balexandre-thanks a lot. I will implement this and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

Replacing `**"<td>" + linktopage + "</td>" +**`, with `<td><asp:Panel id="lnktoPage" /></td>`

And add it from the code, `lnktoPage.Controls.Add(lnk);`

Note that `Panel` renders as `DIV` on client side.

Or... you can create the html link dynamically:

```
string strID = "someID";
string strLink = @"<a id=""" + strID + @"" +
                @" onclick="" " + lnk_clickMethodName + @" "" " +
                @"href=""http://www.w3schools.com"">Visit W3Schools.com!</a>";
```

So, your final method would look something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    string strID = "lnk" + i.ToString();
    string strLink = @"<a id=""" + strID + @"" +
                    @" onclick="" " + lnk_clickMethodName + @" "" " +
                    @"href=""http://www.w3schools.com"">Visit W3Schools.com!</a>";
    StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();

    html.Append(@"<tr style='height:30px;'>");
    html.Append(@"<td>" + firstname + "</td>");
    html.Append(@"<td>" + surname + "</td>");
    html.Append(@"<td>" + email + "</td>");
    html.Append(@"<td>" + mobile + "</td>");
    html.Append(@"<td>" + strLink + "</td>");
    html.Append(@"</tr>");
}
```

Comment: i m getting this error                                  Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'void'

Answer (score 0):

instead of link button, use `href` tag; it will be easy.....

Comment: i used this code <a href="<%#MetthodToCall(); %>">Call C# Method</a> but no luck